# Reading XML same name sub-element python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to XML parsing and python too .I need to get to the tree subelements and print all of them.

I have an XML file which goes like this. Here is my file- 
https://gofile.io/?c=OXcdue

- allocations
  --queue
  ---subelements of queue
  ---queue(subelement)
  ----subelement of this queue
  ----queue
  ----queue

My requirement is to read all the queues which has subqueues and their subqueues.

Comment: I only want to print queue pireporting_q1- "all attributes and sub elements"+ "atscale_rtam_mr_sq1" with all subelements+ "atscale_spark_sq1"  with all subelemets- Desired result is here -     <queue name="pireporting_q1">
      <minResources>6960000 mb,1160 vcores,87 disks</minResources>
      <maxResources>10440000 mb,1740 vcores,130 disks</maxResources>
      <queue name="atscale_rtam_mr_sq1">
      </queue>
      <queue name="atscale_spark_sq1">
      </queue>
    </queue>

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you want.  The comment is very hard to read. Add the content of he XML file.

Comment: Please check the file in the link. It's not allowing me to add file here. This is my first post. Let me know how do i add my code here without it giving me n error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below (Using no external library)

```
import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<allocations>
    <queue name="bdpaas_express_q1">
      <minResources>12000 mb,2 vcores,1 disks</minResources>
      <maxResources>18000 mb,3 vcores,2 disks</maxResources>
      <aclSubmitApps> xyz</aclSubmitApps>
      <aclAdministerApps> xyz</aclAdministerApps>
      <label>allnodes</label>
    </queue>
    <queue name="dl_priority_q1">
      <minResources>8496000 mb,1416 vcores,108 disks</minResources>
      <maxResources>12768000 mb,2128 vcores,162 disks</maxResources>
      <aclSubmitApps> dla_grp</aclSubmitApps>
      <aclAdministerApps> dla_grp</aclAdministerApps>>
      <label>fastnodes</label>
    </queue>
    <queue name="pireporting_q1">
      <minResources>6960000 mb,1160 vcores,87 disks</minResources>
      <maxResources>10440000 mb,1740 vcores,130 disks</maxResources>
      <queue name="atscale_rtam_mr_sq1">
        <minResources>6000000 mb,1000 vcores,75 disks</minResources>
        <maxResources>9000000 mb,1500 vcores,112 disks</maxResources>
        <aclSubmitApps> atscalep</aclSubmitApps>
        <aclAdministerApps> atscalep</aclAdministerApps>
        <label>allnodes</label>
      </queue>
      <queue name="atscale_spark_sq1">
        <minResources>960000 mb,160 vcores,12 disks</minResources>
        <maxResources>1440000 mb,240 vcores,18 disks</maxResources>
        <aclSubmitApps> atscalep</aclSubmitApps>
        <aclAdministerApps> atscalep</aclAdministerApps>
        <label>allnodes</label>
      </queue>
    </queue>
  <queuePlacementPolicy>
    <rule create="false" name="specified" />
    <rule name="reject" />
  </queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
queues = root.findall('.//queue')
for queue in queues:
  if queue.find('./queue'):
    print(ET.tostring(queue, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queue name="pireporting_q1">
   <minResources>6960000 mb,1160 vcores,87 disks</minResources>
   <maxResources>10440000 mb,1740 vcores,130 disks</maxResources>
   <queue name="atscale_rtam_mr_sq1" />
   <queue name="atscale_spark_sq1" />
</queue>
```

Comment: Hi , I have a very big XML file , this was just an example what i gave. What are my options other then from string method?

Comment: fromstring is just for the answer. You can use 'parse'

Comment: could you also please tell me how do i iterate over the parent and subqueue tags separately here? Thanks for helping....

Comment: @user2910022 I am not sure I understand. Does my code solve your problem and you get the output you are looking for? What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lxml` library to parse any xml content. This library is better than the standard `xml` library as it allows you to get the namespace of the xml document if necessary (not needed in your case).

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(path_to_xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for children in root.getchildren():
    print (children.tag)

    for child in children:
        print(child.tag, child.text)
```

Refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for more information on how to access various parts of your xml file and recursively finding all subelements.. This documentation is for the standard `xml` library but is also supported in the `lxml` library as `lxml` is built on top of `xml`.

Comment: Namespace in xml is a way of assigning elements and attributes to a group. This allows you to have elements with the same name but avoid conflict because they are assigned to a different group. Namespaces are defined at the top of xmls like so:

<element xmlns:name = "URL">  

If you try and parse this using the normal xml library, it will not find the namespace whereas the lxml has a  method to do exactly so.

Comment: Just wanted to give a reason for using lxml over xml.

Comment: The xml library doesn't deal with namespaces very well in my experience especially if the namespace is None.